# Iphone browser (Most ios same) did not show the color , but android and PC browser can show

Tags: php, android, ios, css, iphone

Here is my code . Missing any attribute for ios ?

```
html.no-overflowscrolling.sidebar-light:not(.dark) .sidebar-left .nano {
    background: #126C9E ;
    box-shadow: -5px 0 0 #F6F6F6 inset;

}
```

Here is where i call the class.

echo '';

```
        echo '    <div class="sidebar-header">';
        echo '        <div class="sidebar-title">';
        echo '           <span>'.$lang["M01076"][$language].'</span>';
        echo '        </div>';
        echo '        <div class="sidebar-toggle hidden-xs" data-toggle-class="sidebar-left-collapsed" data-target="html" data-fire-event="sidebar-left-toggle">';
        echo '            <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-label="Toggle sidebar"></i>';
        echo '        </div>';
        echo '    </div>';

        echo '    <div class="nano">';
        echo '        <div class="nano-content">';
        echo '            <nav id="menu" class="nav-main" role="navigation">';
        echo '                <ul class="nav nav-main">';
```

Comment: Could it have something to do with a media query? The bottom screenshot is wider, and I notice that the hamburger is missing from it as well.

Comment: @MrLister there is two different browser , the first one is screenshot from PC , second is Iphone 4s safari browser. Wider is not the problem . And what you mean hamburger.

Comment: The icon consisting of three lines to the top right of the first screenshot is called a "hamburger menu". Since 1) this only is visible in the first screenshot, and 2) menus like that have a tendency to be only visible on narrower screens, I wondered if you had a media query causing the differences.

Comment: @MrLister ok , i did not use media query for this . If is media problem , android should got problem too rite? But i test with my friend android phone , did not have this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I cannot comment.

If you use the `background-color` property instead of `background` ?

By the way, you can use [css prefixer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix). [This tool](https://autoprefixer.github.io/) is very effective.

Hope that help you,

Comment: `background` and `background-color` do not need prefixing.